# extracting the most mentioned from a data

Tags: python, nlp

I have a csv data with Tweets text as df['Tweets'] I would like to extract the ten most common words that have @ before them and their frequincies. In other words, I want to know what are the mlst mentions?  I also want to plot them in with a bar graph for visualization.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See how you can provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help us solve your problem. Provide a sample of your dataframe and show what you have tried (code) so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
from collections import defaultdict

freqs = defaultdict(int)

for value in df['Tweets']:
    if value.startswith('@'):
        freqs[value] += 1

freqs_tuple = [(key, value) for key, value in freqs.items()]
freqs_tuple = sorted(freqs_tuple, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

The first 10 values will be the ones you need.

Comment: how will I plot the most frequent words after I create the freqs_tuple ? Also it takes the whole tweet I want only one word after the @

Comment: To get one word, use value.split()[0]. Fot the plotting, you will have a word as a first item of a tuple and the number as a second item